# Dynamically Sort with Multiple Order By Arguments in XQuery

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I would like to sort documents by multiple properties which may or may not be range-indexed in MarkLogic 8.

Ideally I would have an XQuery function which will accept a sequence of nodes, a sequence of properties to sort by as strings, and a sequence of directions to sort by as strings.

I have accomplished this with a `xdmp:value` call, see below. However this is vulnerable to injection. Would anyone be able to help with a solution using `xdmp:unpath` or `xdmp:invoke` or an entirely different solution?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:sort-dynamically(
  $nodes as node()*,
  $sortbys as xs:string*,
  $directions as xs:string*
  ) as node()*
{
  (: build the components for the order by string
    model: order by node//property direction
  :)
  let $order-bys := 
    for $i in 1 to count($sortbys)
    return
      "$node//" || $sortbys[$i] || " " || $directions[$i]

  (: join the order bys, separated by comma + space :)
  let $order-bys-string := fn:string-join($order-bys, ", ") || " "

  (: create the eval string
    model: for node in nodes
            order by
              node//property1 direction1, node//property2 direction2
            return
              node
  :)
  let $eval-string :=
      fn:concat(
        "for $node in $nodes ",
        "order by ",
          $order-bys-string,
        "return $node"
      )

  (: evaluate the sort :)
  return
    xdmp:value(
      $eval-string
    )
};

let $nodes := (
  xdmp:unquote('{"col1": "1", "col2": "a"}'),
  xdmp:unquote('{"col1": "1", "col2": "a"}'),
  xdmp:unquote('{"col1": "1", "col2": "b"}'),
  xdmp:unquote('{"col1": "2", "col2": "a"}')
  )
let $sortbys := ("col1", "col2")
let $directions := ("ascending", "descending")

return
  local:sort-dynamically($nodes, $sortbys, $directions)
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have more flexibility if you could use [`cts:search`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) and [`cts:index-order`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order), but that seems no option as you like to pass in a sequence of nodes (potentially constructed in memory like in your example), and might not have range indexes for all sort keys.

Keep in mind though that `cts:search` with `cts:order` would give best sorting performance.

All in all, this leaves you with little options. Using `xdmp:value` can be seen as a security risk, but you can counteract that with strict input validation. Instead of using `$sortbys as xs:string*`, you could use `$sortbys as xs:QName+`. And instead of `$directions as xs:string*`, you could use `$ascending as xs:boolean+` (together with some code adjustments). That would make code injection impossible..

HTH!

Comment: If you find yourself compelled to use xdmp:value e.a. after all, then look into using Amps, so you won't have to assign xdmp:value priv to an actual user, just to a particular function.